# How to collect data from a form with named inputs using Express (already using bodyParser/express.json)

Tags: express

**The form submit reaches my router, but without the data.**

**Solved: Replace `express.json()` middleware with `express.urlencoded()`. See my answer for "why".**

(Metaphor: The form is a bus and pressing submit button is collecting passengers at a bus stop and then taking off to the server. This bus shuts the door on that would-be passenger's face. The passenger's running behind it, begging the bus to stop, but the bus continues and arrives at the server empty. I need help replacing this incompetent bus driver.
)

**I'm using Express v4.17.00 and body-parser v1.19.00 (I know it's optional).**

HTML fix attempts:

- [x] Inputs are named
- [x] Values exist
- [x] Switch from `type="hidden" to type="text" and back
- [x] Switch between button[type="submit"] and input[type="submit"]
- [x] Deleting data-fhqwhgads13 (Vue value) from the input
- [x] Passing a more basic value into value
- [x] Use Mozilla's form example instead of my own form (Why I suspect I'm messing up with Express)

Express fix attempts:

- [x] Switch between bodyParser.json() and express.json()
- [x] Use bodyParser.text(), .raw()
- [x] Print the whole req to see if the body's somewhere else.

**With the above fixes, `console.log(req.body)` always shows `{}`. I'm using MDN's example in my MRE, so I think I'm missing something with Express.**

[Here's my MRE repo](https://github.com/Crowbrammer/formtest)

I expect the data to go into my /store-schedule post route, have the data as part of the req object, and I should be able to use it.

However `console.log(req.body)` gives me {} no matter what form inputs are used. There are no error messages.

Comment: can you add the code from your client that sends request and your express route definition?

Comment: @BorysKupar Note that I've just solved this. The [MRE](https://github.com/Crowbrammer/formtest) is linked. The client-side is dist/index.html. The express route def is in index.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing forms work by encoding data into the body of a packet sent with a post request. I guess this is what's `URL encoded` refers to. This differs from a JSON request. I have little experience in transmitting and requesting JSON. I just know that it's different from a JSON request/response.

So, switching `express.json()` to `express.urlencoded()` gave me my data at the `/store-schedule` route of the server.

```js
// app.use(express.json()); Doesn't work.
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // Works
```